# How to display the full output of ipynb in visual studio code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

this been bothering me for quite some time everytime I need to see the data in VSC in keeps showing the preview of the data instead of the full data
[it only shows the preview and not the full dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvNCS.png)

I tried opening settings and change the line limits to 500 and 1000 but it only show the full preview of long data not width wise